# make variables in loops (current loop index as their names)

Tags: c++, loops, declaration

Is it possible to making variables in loops? I need a unknown(1-50) number of lists.It changes every time code runs and I dont want to make lists more than I need

it look likes I need to write a thing that I already tried so:

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < number of tools; i++){
    list<int> listNumber%i;   //listNumber1,listNumber2...
}
```

Comment: No it's not possible in c++. You can use a `std::map<std::string,std::list<int>>` though.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ how so?do I need to make 50 keys and values?

Comment: "Indexed variables" are arrays

Comment: @user5730138 Using something like `"listNumber1"`, `"listNumber2"`etc. as the map keys.

Comment: You can use the same name on each iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters there is no sense to declare a local variable in a loop with different names in each iteration because the scope of the variable is the body of the loop.

```
for(int i = 0 ; i < number of tools; i++){
    list<int> listNumber%i;   //listNumber1,listNumber2...
}
```

So for example each iteration of the loop will know nothing about created lists in the previous iterations.

You could for example declare a list of lists before the loop and use data member `back()`  to access the last created list in each iteration

```
list<list<int>> lst;
for(int i = 0 ; i < number of tools; i++){
    lst.push_back( list<int>() );
    // process the created list using lst.back()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to declare a variable number of variables, or name them dynamically.

If you want to construct `number_of_tools` count of lists and access them using an index, then what you can have is an array of lists:

```
auto lists = std::vector<std::list<int>>(number_of_tools);
```

Then the first list is `lists[0]` and so on.

If instead, you simply wanted to use a different list in each iteration of the loop, and throw the list away after the iteration, then you can simply declare the list inside the loop as you do, but you don't need to (and you can't) change the name of the variable.